# How to return query result in android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new in android developer ,I'm a programmer Delphi and Lazarus,
I have a program using SQLite Database and I'm trying to get the
same program in android, but I have many questions.

I need a method to return an result of an select like:

```
SELECT * from tmc_configuracao ORDER BY cod_configuracao DESC
```

After that i will send this result to a scrollingtable" 
I have no idea how to do this.

Anyone can help me with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String query="SELECT * from tmc_configuracao ORDER BY cod_configuracao DESC";
Cursor cursor=(instance of SQLiteDatabase).rawQuery(query);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  String result_0=cursor.getString(0);
  String result_1=cursor.getString(1);
  //and so on
}
cursor.close();
(instance of SQLiteDatabase).close();
```

Comment: `rawQuery()` takes at least 2 parameters: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: You can replace the second parameter with `null` if you do not want to have any selectionArgs. `Cursor testCursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);`